# Embarcadero linker errors

Tags: c++, openssl, linker, c++builder-xe2

I am trying to use `OpenSSL` crypting/decrypting methods in C++ Embarcadero project (**Embarcadero® C++Builder® XE2 Version 16.0.4429.46931**).
I am facing linker errors on each method/object used from the OpenSSL libs:

```
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_aes_256_cbc' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_EncryptInit_ex' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_ERR_print_errors_fp' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_EncryptUpdate' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_EncryptFinal_ex' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_BIO_dump_fp' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_DecryptInit_ex' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_DecryptUpdate' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Erreur] Error: '_EVP_DecryptFinal_ex' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\ADMIN_ISS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\OPENSSL.OBJ
```

I have found many clues about this type of issues on these webpages but no one worked for me.

I have verified my inclusion and library paths, I have used implib.exe to convert ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll into .lib (I am running 32 bit OS as dev environment) and added it to the project.

Despite this, still the link errors. I don't know what I have done wrong.

I have always had this type of issue when creating new projects and trying to use libraries in them.
Using libraries seems so complicated in this IDE...

Does anybody have some clues on what to check to make it work please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly related: [https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/OpenSSL](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/OpenSSL)

Comment: You did not say which version of the DLLs you are using, and which version of the OpenSSL SDK you are using. It sounds like you may have a mismatch between them.

Comment: I have installed OpenSSL V3.0.7 for Windows 32bits.
Since I have generated the .lib from the dll I think I don't have to use the dll anymore.
Am I right?